# Table does not exist in mysql database

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

> I use JPA for database, I properly define one to many and one to one
> join in my entity class but it is not able to create table for my
> receipt entity class . I do not understand where I make mistake. I
> complete check the entity class but I am not able to find my mistake.
> Below type of error I get when run the application.

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table receipt add constraint FK57qulpfkyxvba4mmdup6l3vot foreign key (problem_id) references disease (problem_id)" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:562) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:507) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at com.nillmani.hospitalmanagement.HospitalManagementApplicationKt.main(HospitalManagementApplication.kt:13) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hospital-management.receipt' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:764) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

> Receipt.kt

```
package com.nillmani.hospitalmanagement.entity

import java.time.LocalDate
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
data class Receipt(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val receipeId:Long=-1,
    val details :String="",
    val barcode : String ="",
    val drug_details: String="",
    val usage : String ="",
    val delivery_Date : LocalDate= LocalDate.now(),
    val diseaseId:Long=-1,//refere to  problmeID
    val patientId:Long=-1,
    val status : Int=0,
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "problemId",referencedColumnName = "problemId")
    val disease: Disease
)
```

> Disease.kt

```
package com.nillmani.hospitalmanagement.entity

import com.nillmani.hospitalmanagement.entity.enum.ProblemStatus
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
data class Disease(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val problemId:Long=-1,
    val diseaseName:String="",
    val diseaseDetails:String="",
    val problemStatus : ProblemStatus,
    var status : Int=0,
    val seekPersonId : Long=-1,//Basically Belongs form patientID
    val admissionId : Long =-1,
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL],fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "patientid",referencedColumnName = "patientid")
    val patient: Patient,
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL],fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "disease")
    val receipes :List<Receipt> = ArrayList()
)
```

> I provide join between these two table ,but every entity class exist
> in database but receipt entity class not able to exist in database.
> what is the reason for this type of issue
> application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/hospital-management
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    generate-ddl: true

app:
  jwt:
    secret: ArbitrarySecretKey

    expiration-in-ms: 864000000
    token:
      prefix: Bearer
    header:
      string: Authorization
```

> application.properties

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Jpa with Hibernate you can either set
`spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` or
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` in your application.properties file
[to initialize the tables](https://springhow.com/spring-boot-database-initialization/)

**NOTE**: setting ddl-auto to create will drop your table every time you restart the application. [You might want to use update instead.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl)

Comment: I already try these tricks but nothing happen. You don't under stand my question, I have lot of  entity class tables in my application every entity class store as a table in database but only the receipt entity class not able to store in database as a table. This issue is only for Receipt table not for other table

Comment: My bad. Can you check the hibernate logs on startup (by setting `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug` in `application.properties`). Is there ever a `create table  [...]` statement ?

Comment: I already debug it but nothing happen .get same issue. I already try  this method. I post all my db connection details please check it

Comment: You can't use both application.properties and application.yml. Since all your config is yml, use `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL: debug` 
in application.yml . You should see new logs on startup.

Comment: I define it in yml but nothing happen

Comment: I created a [minimal reproduction](https://github.com/lookslikeitsnot/stackoverflow-69655729.git) with tests and don't have the issue. Looks like we're missing some information. Do you have any custom Configuration files that override properties.yml ?

Comment: No, I think this type of error generated from Mapping side .OneTOMany, ManyToOne,I make Big mistake in joining column

Comment: The only mistake you made in mapping was not putting a capital "i" in id for patientId. The fact that the table isn't created has nothing to do with mapping. Check [the code on GitHub](https://github.com/lookslikeitsnot/stackoverflow-69655729), you'll see it works.